# Alexa keeps giving error

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I get this error from Alexa trying to run Service Simulator since yesterday

> There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP
>   503 : Service Unavailable

Is it a known issue? Is Alexa down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It was!](https://aws.amazon.com/message/41926/) You can always [monitor the health of the AWS servers with this link](https://status.aws.amazon.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to check is to go to lambda -> functions, then run test. If that fails as well, it's an issue with AWS.  I had the same issue again last week.